# Add another column on Dynamic Pivot Table and count the null/0 values

Tags: mysql, mariadb, pivot-table

i have a working dynamic pivot code. i'm stuck on this almost 1 week since i was trying to find a way to add another column that counts the 0's or null.

```
  SET @sql_dynamic:= (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT
                        (DISTINCT 
                          CONCAT('if(sum(if(attendance_date = "',
                              date_format(attendance_date, '%Y-%m-%d'),
                              '",1,0))=0,0,attendance_status) AS `',
                               date_format(attendance_date, '%Y-%m-%d'),'`'
                            )
                           ) from attendance
                             WHERE subject_id=1 AND attendance_month = "January"
                      );


             SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT studentidnumber, student_fullname, 
                          subject_id, attendance_month, ', @sql_dynamic,'
                            FROM attendance
                            WHERE subject_id=1 AND attendance_month = "January"
                            GROUP BY studentidnumber'
                         );

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;`
```

which results to this:

[pivot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eU1Y.png)

now i want to add another column to the dynamic table which counts the 0 or null values.

pls help.

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate table with all the dates in it.  (Or at least enough dates to handle your date range.)  MariaDB (not MySQL) has a neat feature of sequence tables.  For example, `seq_1_to_100` is a virtual table that contains all the integers from 1 to 100.  Use something like that, together with `+ INTERVAL seq` to generate all the dates.  Then `LEFT JOIN` with our table to get the "missing" dates to generate `NULL` values.  Change those to `0` with `IFNULL()`, if desired.